# PHP exec route add no response, no errors

Tags: php, unix, exec, routes

I have this line:

```
$lastLine = exec("/sbin/route add -net 127.0.0.1", $out, $retVar);
```

the $lastLine and $out are empty and $retVar is 7. What does this mean?
I was expected a message like `SIOCADDRT operation not permitted` because I didn't execute this command as a sudoer but instead I get nothing. Why? I want errors :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
$lastLine = exec("/sbin/route add -net 127.0.0.1 2>&1", $out, $retVar);
```